# Error con PrimeVue Dropdown this.visibleOptions.findIndex is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, primevue

He estado intentando añadir en el componente de primeVue unos objetos que vienen consumidos de un api en un dropdown y me ha generado el siguiente error:
`this.visibleOptions.findIndex is not a function`

Este es el codigo de consumo con axios

```
const local = reactive({
    secciones: {}
})
async function getSecciones() {
    try {
        //fetch datos de la api
        const response = await ApiService.get("cotizacion");
        local.secciones = response.data;
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

Este es el código de los dropdowns

```
<Card v-for="seccion in local.secciones" class="m-1" :key="seccion.id">
    <template #title>
      {{ seccion.nombre }}
    </template>
    <template #content>
      <Dropdown :options="seccion.sub_secciones" optionLabel="nombre"
         placeholder="Selecciona la sub sección" class="w-full m-2">
      </Dropdown>
    </template>
</Card>
```

Agradezco la ayuda,  no he podido solucionarlo aún.

He probado pasarlo comprobarlo como un array y más metodos pero me sigue apareciendo el error, espero que pueda cargar los datos y que funcione.
Este el json que me llega y la idea es que las sub_secciones se llenen en el dropdown

```
 {
  "id": 1,
  "nombre": "Técnicas",
  "sub_secciones": {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "nombre": "Impresión",
      "tipo_productos": {
        "1": {
          "id": 1,
          "nombre": "Impresión",
          "productos": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "nombre": "Papel"
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "nombre": "Papel 2"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿En qué lugar estás utilizando el `this.visibleOptions`? ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta para agregar esa parte del código?